# Can a third-party JS access first-party localstorage?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-domain, local-storage

When I embedded a JS hosted on lets say, xyz.com on an webpage hosted on abc.com, it seemed xyz.com/test.js could read and write all key-values set on and by abc.com. Isn't that considered huge security hole? Are sites advised to not store any user sensitive information in localstorage when you are planning to use any third-party JS like from Google Analytics?

Here is an example - https://jsfiddle.net/kuldeepk/eqawezd6/1/

```
localStorage.setItem('first-party', 'first-party');
window.Test.setKeyValue('third-party', 'third-party')
console.log(window.Test.getKey('first-party'))
console.log(localStorage.getItem('third-party'));
```

window.Test is declared in third-party JS

Comment: Yes, any JS loaded on a page can access cookies and localStorage from the page's domain. That's one of the reasons you should not store sensitive data in the browser (if you must, encrypt it serverside and decrypt it serverside). In France, we have laws that forbid storing data locally without the user's consent, and storing non-encrypted sensitive data like user emails, password, etc.

Comment: Interesting. I am puzzled why browsers allowed this security hole, while cookies don't suffer this same design flaw.

Comment: _"Cookies don't suffer this same design flaw"_ ? https://jsfiddle.net/scwo1ba9/

Comment: In that example cookie is set in the same domain. cookie set in abc.com can't be read by xyz.com

Comment: There is a simple test you can do to check this in your local machine. Map a completely different domain on your hosts file, create a js file who reads the storage in your application and include it in your index.html, but using this custom domain. When you access your index.html from your localhost, as an example, the script will be able to read the storage values even loaded from another domain.

Answer (score 0):

> Are sites advised to not store any user **sensitive information**

Hell no, with your without using *any third-party JS*

Everything in js or html can be read by everybody visiting your site, no matter if it's in localstorage or elsewhere in the front-end.

Just press <kbd>F12</kbd> and look at the entire front-end source code stackoverflow has to offer.

Comment: Yes I understand that part. I wasnt referring to exactly username/password kind of stuff, but even the general application related data, seems like this data can be tampered with by third-party js without first-party knowing it. This is not the case with cookies. I guess im just puzzled by this whole loop hole

Comment: A cookie can be read as well. @KuldeepKapade. Just click blex' fiddle below your question.

Comment: In that example cookie is set in the same domain. cookie set in abc.com can't be read by xyz.com

Comment: @KuldeepKapade The xyz.com script can read your cookies when you load it into your page. Nothing prevents it from sending your data to their own servers for later use. The same goes for localStorage. They both have that "flaw"...